# Knockout js: Bind checkbox enable when boolean is false

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js

Each of my elements has IsAnabled and IsDeafult. If IsDefault = true, then the checkbox should be disabled.

When I do like this it works, except I want the oppsite effect for "enable":

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsEnabled, enable: IsDefault" />
```

I have tried:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsEnabled, enable: !IsDefault" />
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsEnabled, enable: IsDefault == 'false'" />
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsEnabled, enable: IsDefault != 'true'" />
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsEnabled, enable: IsDefault != true" />
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsEnabled, enable: IsDefault == '0'" />
```

but still no luck...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would recommend you to read the following article: [10 Things to Know About KnockoutJS](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/10-things-to-know-about-knockoutjs-on.html)
Quote from the article:

> Most bindings will call ko.utils.unwrapObservable on the value passed
>   to it, which will safely return the value for both observables and
>   non-observables. However, in a binding if you use an observable in an
>   expression, then you need to reference it as a function. Likewise, in
>   code you typically need to reference your observables as functions,
>   unless you actually want to pass the observable itself (not the
>   value).

So you should add `()` to observable when you use them in an expression:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsEnabled, enable: !IsDefault()" />
```